# automatic download of a file by entering the URL in the search engine with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, download

I want to modify the code of a page so that when entering the URL of the site the automatic download of a file starts. Now we must enter the URL and click on a button for the download to start, this last step is the one I want to avoid. The code is with HTML and JavaScript.